# How to use grid with Sizegrip in Python class

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have an app with grids in frames and am having trouble using all `grid()` and no `pack()`.
I have simplified my App to isolate this problem.

Using `pack()` it resizes correctly, but with `grid()` it does not.

What am I doing wrong?

Here are the two examples:

1. with some `pack()`:

   ```
   from tkinter import *
   from tkinter import ttk

   class App(Frame):
       def __init__(self, parent):
           mframe = Frame.__init__(self, parent)
           self.pack(fill = 'both', expand = True)
           ttk.Sizegrip(mframe).pack(side = 'right')

           self.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
           self.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)

           Text(self, width = 20, height = 2).grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = 'nsew')

   root = Tk()
   App(root)
   root.mainloop()
   ```
2. with only `grid()`:

   ```
   from tkinter import *
   from tkinter import ttk

   class App(Frame):
       def __init__(self, parent):
           mframe = Frame.__init__(self, parent)
           self.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = 'nsew')
           ttk.Sizegrip(root).grid(row = 1, sticky = 'se')

           self.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
           self.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)

           Text(self, width = 20, height = 2).grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = 'nsew')

   root = Tk()
   App(root)
   root.mainloop()
   ```

.

Comment: You missed `parent.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)` and `parent.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)`.

Comment: @SzieberthAdam Thank you! That was it. I also just noticed that I had Sizegrip(root) on the second one, It should have been Sizegrip(mframe).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using grid to place the `App` frame in its parent, but you aren't configuring the weight of the rows and columns in the parent. If you use grid, you must configure row and column weights to get proper resize behavior.

You need to add something like:

```
parent.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
parent.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

However, I recommend that you do *not* make a call to `self.grid` inside the class. It's better design to let the function that creates a widget decide where that widget goes. While it doesn't really matter in this tiny example, it will matter once you start making more complex GUIs.

Also, it's perfectly fine to mix grid and pack, as long as you don't use them both in the same master window. Since the App is the only widget in the root widget, it's a little easier to use pack in this case, since you don't have to remember to configure the rows and columns. I would change your code to do this:

```
root = Tk()
App(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```

... and then remove the call to `self.grid` inside the **init** function, make make the size grid a child of the frame rather than root

Comment: I tried this but can't get the sizegrip into the lower right corner with pack().

Comment: @Harvey: you might need to adjust the default padding options of pack; I don't recall off the top of my head what they are. Generally speaking, though, if you can put it in the corner with grid then you can put it in the corner with pack. But if you're more comfortable with grid, there's no reason not to use it.

Comment: So what do I do with your recommendation about "do not make a call to self.grid inside the class". Can you post a complete working modification (using either pack or grid)? I want to understand this.